# Connection between LocalServer and Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0

I have one question related flutter app development.
The Question is, " Is it possible to implement OAuth2 in flutter without firebase?

Basically I want to link my Android Application with own localserver to authenticate users. Every person first register there application with firebase then move further.
If there is any solution please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use oauth2 client package https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2 
Github https://github.com/dart-lang/oauth2

Client Credentials Grant code snippet

```
// This URL is an endpoint that's provided by the authorization server. It's
// usually included in the server's documentation of its OAuth2 API.
final authorizationEndpoint =
    Uri.parse("http://example.com/oauth2/authorization");

// The OAuth2 specification expects a client's identifier and secret
// to be sent when using the client credentials grant.
//
// Because the client credentials grant is not inherently associated with a user,
// it is up to the server in question whether the returned token allows limited
// API access.
//
// Either way, you must provide both a client identifier and a client secret:
final identifier = "my client identifier";
final secret = "my client secret";

// Calling the top-level `clientCredentialsGrant` function will return a
// [Client] instead.
var client = await oauth2.clientCredentialsGrant(
    authorizationEndpoint, identifier, secret);

// With an authenticated client, you can make requests, and the `Bearer` token
// returned by the server during the client credentials grant will be attached
// to any request you make.
var response = await client.read("https://example.com/api/some_resource.json");

// You can save the client's credentials, which consists of an access token, and
// potentially a refresh token and expiry date, to a file. This way, subsequent runs
// do not need to reauthenticate, and you can avoid saving the client identifier and
// secret.
await credentialsFile.writeAsString(client.credentials.toJson());
```